# How to compare buttons populated from SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

OK, i've managed to import prepopulated sqlite database to my Assets folder and read from it and also randomly set my question to my TextView, and A column to the left side button and B column to the right side buttons. Below you can see my dbhelper, test helper and my game class. And here i'm stuck. I need to compare left and right side, when a user click on a button on one side, for example on A4, to be correct, he then need to click to B4. How can I compare this?

[image]

Database helper:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
//destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/rs.androidaplikacije.spojnice/databases/"; 
private static String DB_NAME ="pitanja.sqlite";// Database name
private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
private final Context mContext;
private static final String KEY_ID = "_ID";
private static final String KEY_PITANJE = "PITANJE";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tblPitanja";

public DataBaseHelper(Context mojContext) 
{
    super(mojContext, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
    DB_PATH = mojContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = mojContext;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets


        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try 
        {
            //Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
    /*Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
    */

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() 
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        Log.w("DataBaseHelper", "Upgrading database!!!!!");
          onCreate(arg0);

    }

}
```

TestAdapter:

```
public class TestAdapter 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public TestAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } 
        catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

     public Cursor getTestData(String whereClause)
     {;
         try
         {
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblPitanja WHERE 1 = 1 " + whereClause + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             if (mCur!=null)
             {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         }
         catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
}
```

My game class:

```
public class Spojnice extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

LinkedList<Long> mAnsweredQuestions = new LinkedList<Long>();

    private String generateWhereClause(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Long l : mAnsweredQuestions){
            result.append(" AND _ID <> " + l);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
        };

    Button a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8;
    TextView pitanje;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   //full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.spojnice);

        a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA1);
        a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA2);
        a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA3);
        a4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA4);
        a5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA5);
        a6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA6);
        a7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA7);
        a8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA8);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB8);
        pitanje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPitanje);

        nextQuestion();
    }

    private void nextQuestion() {

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{    //Pokusava da otvori db

            mDbHelper.open();  //baza otvorena

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            pitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

            List<String> labelsA = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> labelsB = new ArrayList<String>();

            labelsA.add(c.getString(2));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(4));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(6));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(8));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(10));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(12));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(14));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(16));

            labelsB.add(c.getString(3));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(5));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(7));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(9));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(11));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(13));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(15));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(17));

            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0));
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1));
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a3.setText(labelsA.get(2));
            a3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a4.setText(labelsA.get(3));
            a4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a5.setText(labelsA.get(4));
            a5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a6.setText(labelsA.get(5));
            a6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a7.setText(labelsA.get(6));
            a7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a8.setText(labelsA.get(7));
            a8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0));
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1));
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b3.setText(labelsB.get(2));
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b4.setText(labelsB.get(3));
            b4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b5.setText(labelsB.get(4));
            b5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b6.setText(labelsB.get(5));
            b6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b7.setText(labelsB.get(6));
            b7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b8.setText(labelsB.get(7));
            b8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    }
        finally{    // kada zavrsi sa koriscenjem baze podataka, zatvara db
            mDbHelper.close();
        }


}

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to perform click of `B4` from `A4` then you can use `b4.performClick()` in `onClick()` of `A4`.

Comment: 1. What means "Compare buttons"? Did You stuck determining what button should be clicked next after, for example, B1? And consider idea of using arrays (Button[] a, Button[]b) of buttons instead of a1, a2... Not only because it's good code practice, but also You could refer to buttons using indexes: if button a[i] clicked, then button b[i] should be clicked next, for example.

Comment: Can you give me a code example below in form of an answer of what you ment, I didn't understand what you said? And by compare buttons I ment...lets say you have to connect actors...if you click on the left side Silvester, you need to click on the right side Stallone to be correct. And Silvester is A3 for example in my database, and Stallone is B3.